# Postgres function for NVL

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-12

I'm trying to have `NVL` function in postgres.

```
create or replace function nvl (anyelement, anyelement)
returns anyelement language sql as $$
    select coalesce(cast( $1 as decimal), cast( $2 as decimal))
$$;
```

however this fails on me for the following examples:

```
testdb=> select nvl(1,2);
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return integer
DETAIL:  Actual return type is numeric.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "nvl" during inlining

testdb=> SELECT nvl( sum(balance), 0 ) as b FROM db.bank WHERE user = 123;
ERROR:  function nvl(numeric, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT nvl( sum(balance), 0 ) as b FROM db.bank...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

When I change it to:

```
create or replace function nvl (anyelement, anyelement)
returns anyelement language sql as $$
    select case when $1 is null then $2 else $1 END 
$$;
```

The first example works. But I still have failures with:

```
testdb=> SELECT nvl( sum(balance), 0 ) as b FROM db.bank WHERE user = 123;
ERROR:  function nvl(numeric, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT nvl( sum(balance), 0 ) as b FROM db.bank...
```

Would love some help fixing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors results from a misunderstanding of the use of the `anyelement` type. Read in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC):

> Each position (either argument or return value) declared as anyelement is allowed to have any specific actual data type, but in any given call they must all be the same actual type.

So, you should use the function in the form [it was proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40300936/1995738):

```sql
create or replace function nvl (anyelement, anyelement)
returns anyelement language sql as $$
    select coalesce($1, $2)
$$;
```

and make sure that the actual type of arguments match exactly. If the column `balance` is numeric, the second argument also has to be `numeric`:

```sql
select nvl(sum(balance), 0.0)
-- or
select nvl(sum(balance), 0::numeric)
```

---

Update. The OP says:

> I can not change the SQLs. only adjust the function.

In this case you cannot use `anyelement` arguments. You need to create function with numeric arguments:

```sql
drop function if exists nvl (anyelement, anyelement);

create or replace function nvl (numeric, numeric)
returns numeric language sql as $$
    select coalesce($1, $2)
$$;
```

The drawback is that the function will work only for numeric and/or integer arguments. Postgres allows to overload functions, so you can additionally create functions for other types, e.g.:

```sql
create or replace function nvl (text, text)
returns text language sql as $$
    select coalesce($1, $2)
$$;
```

Comment: I can not change the SQLs. only adjust the function.